# Where do I buy a weather proof combination padlock?

Tags: lock, security

I have a shed that I use a padlock to secure. The last lock I had lasted a year before failing. It cost about $40. My wife prefers combination so she won't need her keys just to work in the yard.

I can't find a good quality, *weather proof* combination lock in the US, can anyone help?

Comment: If this question had been asked today, it would be closed as shopping related or product recommendation. It should not be used as an on-topic reference for questions asked today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed this about a year ago, it's holding up well - no discoloration - (though we haven't had much rain either).  It's stainless steel and feels well built.  It's *not* weather proof, but I hope to get far more than a year out of it.

[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004JVBK0A)

[Master Lock Link](http://www.masterlock.com/product_details/CombinationPadlocks_21457mmWideBody_Set-Your-OwnCombination_No.1174CombinationPadlocks/1174)

[image]

Comment: To follow up on this point, I did order and receive this lock (about $22). It would not open per the instructions and is of such poor quality that I returned it. I will be looking for something of better quality.

Comment: @mmcglynn I'm really sorry it didn't work out for you.  Please feel free to uncheck my answer, and please add an answer if you find a better lock.

Comment: No worries. I bought a Stanley lock (http://www.stanleyhardware.com/default.asp?TYPE=STATIC&PAGE=int_combination.htm), we'll see if it is any better.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a cheap MasterLock for over a decade on my shed and it's not showing any signs of wear. Only downside is that they've been known to have a security flaw (a little internet searching will describe how to determine the combination with only a little trial and error). After a storm, I turn it sideways and the water just pours out, so it's definitely exposed to the elements.

[image: MasterLock]

For harsh elements, you may also want to look at an outdoors or boating store. Their locks are usually designed to resist salt water exposure:

[image: marine lock]

Comment: Good tip on the boating store. You're not likely to find a more extreme environment.

Comment: The [Sesamee Locks](http://www.amazon.com/Sesamee-Keyless-Padlocks-Shackle-Padlock/dp/B001C4TEKU/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top) seem to have good reviews on Amazon too. Several of the reviewers mention using them outside without any problems. (Note I have no affiliation with the brand, just doing some consumer research here.)

Answer (score 2):

You could get a cover for the padlock, something like the [Padlock Saver](http://www.padlocksaver.com/products.htm).

[image]

There are also hasps available that have built in covers, like this.

[image]

I've also seen solutions as simple as attaching a thick piece of rubber to the door/wall, just above the lock to keep it covered.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new lock by ABUS. It's a bit on the expensive side but it's been holding quite well this winter. Mind you, it rained quite a lot this year in London.
It's ABUS 190CS/60mm Heavy Duty. A combination padlock as I have a problem with remembering where I put my keys.
Good luck